# jQuery click events don't work on page, but they work on jsFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I checked js tags are just fine, everything is closed, but the js all of sudden decides not to work. I have the code working in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PRVm8/110/) so I know it has to be something I did or possibly the server. I just need some outside influence to make sure it's not oversight.

This is [the site](http://reinhardtcreative.com/clients/dev/gcn/testing.php) with the problem.
Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".designers").show();
    $('.list').hide();
});

$(".but").click(function(){
    $(".designers").hide();
    $(".list").show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
});

$(".but2").click(function(){
    $(".designers").show();
    $(".list").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Seems like you are binding the event before the element is rendered.

Comment: Hi there, jquery and jqueryUI libraries are differents on website than jsFiddle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The event handlers should go in the ready function as well:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".designers").show();
    $('.list').hide();

    $(".but").click(function(){
        $(".designers").hide();
        $(".list").show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
    });

    $(".but2").click(function(){
        $(".designers").show();
        $(".list").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
    });
});
```

JsFiddle automagically sticks everything in a document ready, that's why it works there and not on your site, as you're trying to fetch the elements before they are added to the DOM.

Comment: Or he could use event delegation. Or, place the script at the end of the document body.

Comment: @crush - this seemed like the easiest and most common way to do it, and it's explained in the documentation as well, so it should'nt be as confusing as delegated event handlers, but good point, you could do it a number of different ways.

Comment: @Jes - seems to work just fine for me, just tried your site again and now it seems to slide whenever you hit the button. Try hitting CTRL-F5 to clear the cache ?

Comment: Thank you so much but for some reason I'm not seeing it even after clearing the cache.

Comment: @Jes - seriously! When visiting [**Your site**](http://reinhardtcreative.com/clients/dev/gcn/testing.php) and clicking the button, the text does'nt move? Try a different browser, I'm using chrome, and it seems to work just fine ?